# Primitive variable updated only once in Angular template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-changedetection

I have a menu that I open on button click and I would like to close on an inner button click.
While the menu opens on the outer button click, it does not refresh the variable in the template, when I click the inner button (even if the variable in the controller ist toggled).

**template**

```
<div class="filter" (click)="openMenu()">
  <div class="inner-menu" [ngClass]="{'showMenu': showMenu }" >

  {{showMenu}} <!-- THIS DOES NOT UPDATE AFTER THE 1.TIME-->

   <div class="btn-container">
     <div class="btn tiny primary" (click)="filterData()">
       Close
     </div>
   </div> 

  </div>
 </div>
```

**controller**

```
openMenu() {
  this.showMenu = true;
}

filterData() {
  this.showMenu = false;   // The value is updated in the controller
  this.applyFilter.emit(true);  // Correctly propagated to the parent
}
```

**scss file**

```
filter {
position: relative;

.inner-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 25rem;

 btn-container {
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 1.5rem;
  }
}

 .showMenu {
   display: block;
 }
}
```

I am sure the solution is extremely obvious, as I developed many other applications and it always worked in a similar way, but at the moment I cannot find the real reason why the variable is not updated in the template but only in the controller.

Comment: Try : `(click)="filterData(); $event.stopPropagation();"`. The click event is probably also caught by the parent `div`, triggering `(click)="openMenu()"` and setting `showMenu` to `true` again.

Comment: @Connors: I just found exactly that was the reason :) But thanks for your hint!!

Answer (score 0):

I was not using `event.stopPropagation();` for inner the button click. Simple yet sometimes not immediate to find.

I corrected my code like this:

```
filterData(event: MouseEvent) {
 event.stopPropagation();  // <- This is new
 this.showMenu = false;
 this.applyFilter.emit(this.sections);
}
```

In the template:

```
<div class="btn tiny primary" (click)="filterData($event)">
   Close
</div>
```

And it worked. I hope this might save some time to someone else!

**UPDATE**

For the sake of completion [here an article](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) explaining potential dangers while using `preventDefault()` so that you can be aware of the side effects if you have to use it in your apps.